# Why doesn't my recursive array search work on this array of data?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a recursive array search function which has previously been working a treat. For some reason though now it appears to be telling me things exist in the array which actually don't.

IE, I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => people
        [groups] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => tom
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => john
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And my recursive search function:

```
function searchArrayRecursive($needle, $haystack){

  foreach ($haystack as $key => $arr) {

    if(is_array($arr)) {

      $ret=searchArrayRecursive($needle, $arr);

      if($ret!=-1) return $key.','.$ret;

    } else {

      if($arr == $needle) return (string)$key;

    }

  }

  return -1;

}
```

If I were to do the following however:

```
$search = searchArrayRecursive('kim',$the_array);

if($search != -1) {

  echo 'result: found<br />';

} else {

 echo 'result: not found';

}
```

I get **result: found**
Its clearly not in the array. Maybe my function never worked. maybe my heads on backwards. Any ideass?

note: I also get **result: found** when I search for tom or john o.O

Comment: The code you posted works just fine on my local machine and on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/KWwjuDjg).

Comment: and what does $search actually contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example works as provided.  Possibly your actual data has mixed case? ('john' != 'John') or possibly extra spaces or a stray newline because they weren't trimmed when the array was created?

Try a var_dump() instead of a print_r().  It should show you the exact nature of the data you are trying to search.  I suspect your data may not be in the format you expect it to be.